# iterrows() of 2 columns and save results in one column

Tags: pandas, postgresql

in my data frame I want to iterrows() of two columns but want to save result in 1 column.for example df is

```html
x       y      
5       10
30     445
70     32
```

expected output is

```html
points      sequence
5             1
10            2 
30            1 
445           2
```

I know about iterrows() but it saved out put in two different columns.How can I get expected output and is there any way to generate sequence number according to condition? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First never use [`iterrows`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316), because really slow.

If want `1, 2` sequence by number of columns convert values to numy array by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and add [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), then for sequence use [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'points': df.to_numpy().ravel(),
                   'sequence': np.tile([1,2], len(df))})
print (df)
   points  sequence
0       5         1
1      10         2
2      30         1
3     445         2
4      70         1
5      32         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([i[1] for i in df.iterrows()])
   points  sequence
0       5         1
1      10         2
2      30         1
3     445         2
```